# Get-AzADUser no longer return Department and AccountEnabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I'm pretty sure that last week I was able to use **Get-AzADUser** to return both **Department** and **AccountEnabled**.

```
Get-AzADUser | where {$_.Mail -eq "abc@xyz.com"} | Select-Object Mail, Department, AccountEnabled

Mail        Department AccountEnabled
----        ---------- --------------
abc@xyz.com
```

When I call up all parameters for a single user I can see that I'm missing content on many fields, I basically only see Name, JobTitle, Mail, and MobileNumber

I'm using an account assigned the roles "**Global reader**" and "**Directory readers**".

(Other parts of my script also stopped working since last week where Get-AzADUsers no longer has a field called "**ObjectId**" but instead the field is simply called "**Id**")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in My Environment and found `Get-AzADUser` not much suitable command as it doesn't appear to return any information about the user (like department, usage location, office info, or basically any properties on the user).

There continues to be a lack of properties returned when comparing `Get-AzureADUser` vs. `Get-AzADUser`:

[image]

[image]

AzureAD Module which is a designed for tasks within AzureAD
Where second one Az which is designed to handle most, if not all of Azure's resources.

you can use the `az` module easliy if you just want to look up the users existance, but if you need to actually administer azure ad i would suggest you go for `azuread`. To connect to a specified tenant with azuread use `connect-azuread -tenantId 'XXXXXX'`.

**Output Using Get-AzureADUser**

I am able to get the `departmentName`

[image]

Reference : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10497

Comment: I see... Maybe I was using Get-AzureADUser back when it worked and then changed to Az when I moved the script to Azure Automation. In any case I think that you have found my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "-Select" and " -AppendSelected" parameters to get the info.

Try the following (working for me)...

```
Get-AzADUser -Select 'Department,AccountEnabled' -AppendSelected -UserPrincipalName "abc@xyz.com" | Select-Object Mail, Department, AccountEnabled


Mail          Department    AccountEnabled
----          ----------    --------------
abc@xyz.com   IT Support    True
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser