# Add members on groups in Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to write a script to add members on a group in PowerShell, i write bellow script seems correct for me my it's not working. please help

```
   $grpname = Read-Host "Please enter group name:"
   $group = Get-AzureADGroup -filter "DisplayName eq '$grpname'"
   $groupId = $group.ObjectId

   $job = Read-Host "Please enter Job title:"
   $userjob = Get-AzADUser -filter "Jobtitle eq '$job'"
   $userId = $userjob.Id

   foreach ($userId in $userIds) {
   Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupId -RefObjectId $userId
   }
   Write-Output " You can see bellow members of ($grpname) : "
   Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "$groupId"
```

Comment: use `Get-AzureADUser`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656379/get-azaduser-no-longer-return-department-and-accountenabled

Comment: You should be using the MSGraph powershell module as well

Comment: Where do you populate `$userIds`? `foreach ($userId in $userIds) {...}` will not do anything as long as `$userIds` is `$Null`

Answer (score 0):

Other than what [Halfix mentioned in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714465/add-members-on-groups-in-azure-powershell#comment133570245_75714465) there is nothing particularly wrong with your code, the only thing that could be happening is that there are no users found having the `jobTitle` equal to the user input in `$job`.

As aside, you should migrate your code to the [Microsoft.Graph Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0) since the [AzureAD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) will be soon deprecated:

[image]

Here is how your code would look using the Graph Cmdlets:

```bash
$grpname = Read-Host "Please enter group name"
$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$grpname'"

if(-not $group) {
    return "No group found with displayName '$grpName'"
}

if($group.Count -gt 1) {
    return "Multiple groups found with displayName '$grpName'"
}

$job = Read-Host "Please enter Job title"
$users = Get-MgUser -Filter "jobTitle eq '$job'"

if(-not $users) {
    return "No users found with jobTitle '$job'"
}

foreach($user in $users) {
    New-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id -DirectoryObjectId $user.Id
}

"You can see bellow members of ($grpname):"
Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id
```

The required permissions to perform this operation are **GroupMember.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All**. See [**Permissions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) section of Graph API Documentation.